# Установка значения атрибута в HttpSession

Tags: servlet, java-ee, java, jsp

Есть сервлет, который проверяет введённые пользователем данные (логин и пароль).
Если такая комбинация есть в БД, то включает сессию, а затем перенаправляет на JSP-страницу:

```
String login = request.getParameter("login");
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("auth", login);
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080//WebApplication2/hello.jsp");
```

В *hello.jsp* я приветствую пользователя и пытаюсь достать `login` из сессии:

```
HttpSession ses = request.getSession();
String user = (String)ses.getAttribute("auth");
out.println(user);
user = (String)session.getAttribute("auth");
out.println(user);
```

Выводит `null` в обоих случаях. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Залейте куда-нибудь архив со своим проектом, посмотрим

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел ответ: почему-то сессия теряется при перенаправлении.

Если написать вот так:

```
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080//WebApplication2/hello.jsp");
```

то сессия теряется. А если вот так:

```
response.sendRedirect("hello.jsp");
```

то сессия работает правильно.

Comment: как раз собирался об этом написать, вы б почитали хоть что-нибудь о Servlet контейнерах, ну и вообще программировании под Web на Java.

Comment: И потом освоить какой-нибудь framework. Spring Web-MVC например.